# A decent text-user-interface stopwatch?

Tags: software-rec, ncurses, text-user-interface

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

but preferably

- [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) (ncurses-based),
- with support for multiple stopwatches (and giving names to them)
- able to survive being closed and re-opened (a stopwatch only needs to remember when it was started)

(Gnome-clocks above only gets 1/3 here. 2/3 would be an improvement for me)

Comment: your question belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jsotola Seems to be on-topic here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec